# Copy table in Databricks

Tags: scala, databricks, delta-lake

How can one copy delta table in databricks from one environment1 to environment2 ?

```
CREATE TABLE environment2table 
SHALLOW CLONE environment1table 
LOCATION dbfs:/environment2table/
```

Answer (score 1):

From the databricks [blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/09/15/easily-clone-your-delta-lake-for-testing-sharing-and-ml-reproducibility.html) on cloning delta lake data:

```
-- SQL
CREATE TABLE delta.`/some/test/location` SHALLOW CLONE prod.events

# Python
DeltaTable.forName(spark, "prod.events").clone("/some/test/location", isShallow=True)

// Scala
DeltaTable.forName(spark, "prod.events").clone("/some/test/location", isShallow=true)
```

Here, instead of *prod* you should give *environment1*, and provide *environment2* location as "/some/test/location".